# Not able to display Java version using PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I am writing Powershell script, which will essentially be a menu driven utility for doing random tasks. One of the feature includes, to display java version. I am using REPLto have it in continues loop. My issue is that the Java version is just not being displayed on the screen. Can anyone please help me with the reason for this or a work around ? Below is the code:

```
 enum Outcome
{
    Continue
    Quit
}
 
 Class Opatch_Manager {
     
     REPL() {

        while($this.ShowMenu() -eq 'Continue') {
            $this.Print()
        }
    }

    Print() {
        Write-Host "Test"
    }
    
   [String] ShowJava() {
     java -version
    }
   
    [Outcome] ShowMenu() {
        $this.ShowJava() 
        return [Outcome]::Quit
     }
     
 }
 
 $obj = New-Object Opatch_Manager
 $obj.REPL()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike direct use of commands in scripts and functions, methods in PowerShell custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)es must use `return` in order to produce output (and the method must declare a suitable return type).

Similarly, *stderr* output - which is what `java -version` produces - isn't automatically passed through.

**Note**:

- Using `java --version` instead, i.e *two* leading `-`, produces *stdout* instead, so that 
  `return java --version` *would* produce output, albeit probably not in the expected format - see below, which discusses the formatting aspect as well as the general case when stderr output must be captured.

Thus, combine `return` with a `2>&1` redirection (simplified example):

```
class Foo {

  [String] ShowJava() {
    return (java -version 2>&1) -join "`n"
   }

}  

[Foo]::new().ShowJava()
```

- `2>&1` redirects stderr (`2`) output to PowerShell's success output stream (the analog to stdout) so that `return` can return it.
- `` -join "`n" `` is used to return the output lines as a single, multi-line string.

  - This is necessary, because your method is declared as `[string]`, whereas output from an external program is reported *line by line* by PowerShell, which becomes an *array* when collected, and PowerShell stringifies arrays (typically) as a *single-line* string, namely by concatenating the (stringified) elements with *spaces*.

    - Note: The simpler `java -version 2>&1 | Out-String` works in principle, but [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) unfortunately invariably adds a *trailing newline* to the resulting string - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444) for a discussion.
  - The alternative is to declare your method as `[string[]]` - then 
    `return java -version 2>&1` will do (and an *array* of lines is returned)

Comment: I have a small question though, why does java -version produces stderr, and java --version  stdout?

Comment: @PrateekJaiswal - that is a good question, and not being a Java user I can only _guess_: `--version` is the syntax used by GNU utilities (the CLIs that come with most Linux distros), and these utilities are expected to print the version information to _stdout_. Perhaps `java` wants to align with these utilities, and perhaps the Java syntax form, `-version`, has always output to _stderr_ instead (for reasons unknown to me).